Dataform procedure not found
I am running multiple Dataform workflows across projects for many months but recently running into a "Procedure not found" error randomly. I can only assume this refers to the temporary stored procedure created by Dataform during execution. I am unable to debug why this happens or how to take remedial actions to prevent this from occurring. Any help is appreciated.
